# SSD drive reserved by W8?

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I have a dualboot setup as described in this answer to [Installing Ubuntu on pre-installed Windows 10 with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/a/228069/149354) I want to take advantage of the SSD drive on Ubuntu without messing up Windows 8.1.

All systems are on `/dev/sda` (including `/boot/efi`) and the solid-state drive appears on `/dev/sdb` in two "unknown" type partitions in GParted -- is it safe to format these and how to best make use of them on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, the SSD "is used only as a cache under Windows" on my laptop as I [found out](http://www.linlap.com/asus_ux32vd) searching for the model name. So it is most likely safe to use it as a swap partition under linux as well in a dualboot setup.